# Why do I keep getting error trying to run npm scripts?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, webpack, visual-studio-code

I am just getting to learn node and webpack. I was following a tutorial, but I keep running into an error. Details of the error and my setup is given below:
[error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wx4x.png)
[log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0lVm.png)

[My setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk1nw.png)

**package.json content**

```
   {
     "name": "test",
      "version": "1.0.0",
        "description": "",
         "main": "index.js",
        "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "build": "webpack"
        },
        "author": "",
        "license": "ISC",
        "devDependencies": {
        "webpack": "^4.43.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
         },
        "dependencies": {
        "path": "^0.12.7"
     }
 }
```

Comment: did u try install module locally

`npm install --save-dev webpack` 

`npm install --save-dev webpack-cli`

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. Could you provide the contents of your package.json file? Also, can you give a link to the tutorial you are following ? Thanks!

Comment: link to tutorial :
[link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzdEpgONurw&t=244s)

Comment: yes, but sadly same result